# How to hide and show HTML element dynamically in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have table for some task, In that table every row has one task. In every row there is status which is controller by one button. Initial status of every task will be show as In Progress and text of Button as Mark Done, But when click on the button then It will change the status of the task as Done and change the text of button as Mark In Progress. If In future If we want to change the status of "Done" task then we can change the status through Button "Mark In Progress". Please see DEMO on[DEMO on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o3ZKESi4d4m2FPUMQxaT?p=preview)

**Angularjs**

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('tasksCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("data.json")
        //$http.get("/todo/api/v1.0/tasks")
        .success(function(response) {
          $scope.tasks = response.tasks;
        });
        $scope.markInProgress=function(task){
             alert("markInProgress");
             title=task.title;
             description=task.description;
             uri=task.uri;
             var data={title: title, description: description, done: false, uri:uri};

             // For server But here there is no server so I assigne data outside $http.put
             $scope.tasks[$scope.index] = data;

             // For server
             $http.put(uri, data)
             .success(function(){
                 $scope.tasks[$scope.index] = data;
             });
        };
        $scope.markDone=function(task){
            alert("markDone");
            title=task.title;
             description=task.description;
             uri=task.uri;
             var data={title: title, description: description, done: true, uri: uri};

             // For server But here there is no server so I assigne data outside $http.put
             $scope.tasks[$scope.index] = data;

             // For server
             $http.put(uri, data)
             .success(function(){
                 $scope.tasks[$scope.index] = data;
             });
        };
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: you can use ng-if="data.done == false" this would show the element as long as $scope.data.done is false ---> if u then mark it as done you can use ng-click="data.done = true" now you marked it as done and it is hiding but your data object needs to be $scope.data instead of var

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of errors.

In your HTML you have to reference the object's "done" property.

```
<div ng-repeat="task in tasks">
  <span ng-show="task.done" class="label label-success">Done</span>
  <span ng-show="!task.done" class="label label-important">In Progress</span>
 </div>
```

In your Angualr functions, $scope.index is the incorrect way to find the index. Instead find the index and use the `var index` in the rest of your function.

```
var index = $scope.tasks.indexOf(task);
$scope.tasks[index].done = true;
```

Comment: You could also have it in the function call by changing the button call to `whateverMethod(task, $index)` and changing the methods to have an additional parameter for the index.

Comment: But I think this will call a wrong index, for example if the list has a sort function - as the $index is the position displayed, rather than the position in the array.

Comment: True, but there was no sorting or filtering on the display, so it would be fine in this use case. Your version is future-proof though, so better if there might be changes to the display.

Comment: @stevenw00 thanks for reply I modify accoding to you http://plnkr.co/edit/o3ZKESi4d4m2FPUMQxaT?p=preview, I test it my local machine it working but I have to reload browser. Please tell me how to make changes without reloading browser...

Comment: Sorry typo in answer, fixed it. `var index` should be `$scope.tasks` not `$scope.task`.

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways, i would use `ng-show` for this.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

you have to ensure, that the value for your "show" variable is set correctly via your angular controllers.

HTML:

```
<div ng-show="myValue"></div>
```

JS:

```
//your controller code
(.....).success(function(){
  $scope.myValue = true;
})
```

if you want to hide you can do it of course by the same way:

```
//your controller code
(.....).success(function(){
  $scope.myValue = false;
})
```

i hope this helps you

Comment: The OP has a couple of errors in the JS that won't assign the myValue correctly. So although this example is the correct way of using ngShow - this is not enough in this case.

Comment: he looks like he knew what he was doing so i thought this answer would be enough for him to understand how dynamically changing divs in angular...